# How to parse multi-word tokens into PrintStream

Tags: java

So I've written code that essentially allows a user to enter the name of a text file to read input from, that looks something like this.

```
I wannabe a <job> when I grow up.
Just like my dad.
Life is <adjective> like that!
```

Using this input, it prompts the user to enter a madLib for the word in <...> My code compiles and functions fine, until I enter a 2 word phrase for , like Police Officer. I'm wondering if there's a way to parse a multi-word phrase and still achieve the same results, because next() only takes the first word, and nextLine() breaks my code. Any suggestions?

```
public static void createMadLib(Scanner console)throws FileNotFoundException{
          System.out.print("Input file name: ");
          String inputFileName = console.next().toLowerCase();;
          File f = new File(inputFileName);
          while(!f.exists()){
             System.out.print("File not found. Try again: ");
             inputFileName = console.next().toLowerCase();
             f = new File(inputFileName);
          }
          System.out.print("Output file name: ");
          String outputFileName = console.next();
          PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(outputFileName));
          System.out.println();

      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
      while(input.hasNextLine()){
         String line = input.nextLine();
         Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
         while(lineScan.hasNext()){
            String token = lineScan.next();
            if(token.substring(0, 1).equals("<") && token.substring(token.length() - 1).equals(">")){
               char firstLetter = token.charAt(1);

               if(firstLetter == 'a' || firstLetter == 'e' || firstLetter == 'i' ||
                  firstLetter == 'o' || firstLetter == 'u'){
                  System.out.print("Please type an " + token.substring(1, token.length() - 1) + ": ");                  
                  token = console.next();
               }else{
                  System.out.print("Please type a " + token.substring(1, token.length() - 1) + ": ");
                  token = console.next();
               }
            }   
            output.print(token + " "); 
           }
          output.println();  
         } 

      }
```

Comment: How does `nextLine()` break your code? IMHO it should be a clean an simple way...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first read the whole template, and then ask for a replacement for each variable it contains.

UPDATE

Or have the template in a file it that's possible. I guess the whole point of having these variables in the text is to allow the same template to be reused with different values for the variable?